# Firebase Dispatch Error Object { "error": "Invalid claim 'kid' in auth header: 'tB0M2A' with iat: '1659290899'", }

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-redux, firebase-authentication, jwt

I am trying to develop a react-native-app but everything was good. Once I have changed the authentication rules in firebase real time database. From that time, I am not able to POST/GET any request from firebase. I am storing the idToken which is returned after a user sign in the application in redux store.

```
case actionTypes.AUTHENTICATE_USER:
        return {
            ...state,
            isAuth: true,
            token: action.payload
        }

export const authUser = token => {
return {
    type: actionTypes.AUTHENTICATE_USER,
    payload: token
}}
```

The Login action code is as follows:

```
export const tryLogin = (email, password, navigate) => dispatch => {
fetch("https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=" + API_KEY, {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
        email: email, password: password, returnSecuretoken: true
    }),
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
})
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        alert("Authentication Failed");
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        if (data.error) {
            alert(data.error.message);
        }
        else {
            dispatch(authUser(data.idToken));
            navigate("Home");
        }
        console.log(data);
    })}
```

And I get the error while running the following code:

```
export const addPlace = place => (dispatch, getState) => {
let token = getState().token;
console.log("Add place Token:", token);
fetch(`https://first-react-native-proje-7df03-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/places.json?auth=${token}`, {
    method: "POST", body: JSON.stringify(place)
})
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log("Dispatch Error", data))}


export const loadPlaces = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
let token = getState().token;
fetch(`https://first-react-native-proje-7df03-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/places.json?auth=${token}`)
    .catch(err => {
        alert("Something Went Wrong, Sorry!");
        console.log(err);
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        const places = [];
        for (let key in data) {
            places.push({
                ...data[key],
                key: key
            })
        }
        dispatch(setPlaces(places));
    })}
```

My firebase rule is as follows as I am still in initial phase:

```
{"rules": {
  ".read": "auth!=null" ,  // 2022-8-4
".write": "auth!=null",  // 2022-8-4
}}
```

I am not getting any way to solve this. Please help.

Answer (score -1):

Solved. The problem was with the returnSecureToken:true. I wrote returnSecuretoken which was creating the error. It will be:

```
export const tryLogin = (email, password, navigate) => dispatch => {
fetch("https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=" + API_KEY, {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
        email: email, password: password, ***returnSecureToken: true***
    }),
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
})
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        alert("Authentication Failed");
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        if (data.error) {
            alert(data.error.message);
        }
        else {
            dispatch(authUser(data.idToken));
            navigate("Home");
        }
        console.log(data);
    })
```

}